# What happened to screen fade-out in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, power-management

In Ubuntu 20.04, with Gnome desktop, after 5 minutes of inactivity (default setting I think; can't remember ever having changed that), there used to be this "fade-out" effect, with the screen slowly turning darker, before turning off entirely. What I liked about this is that it prompted me to briefly touch my mouse or keyboard to prevent the screen from turning off, for example, when reading a text on screen.

After upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04, this default behaviour changed, with the screen now turning off and locking immediately after 5 minutes of inactivity.

In the meantime, I've managed to set a delay between the screen turning off and the screen locking, using `gsettings`. However, I couldn't find anything about this "fade-out" behaviour. What is this called, and can I somehow activate this in Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: It is still present in my DE using the X11 windowing system by defaut 

Comment: I've been running 22.04 for a while, and it was fading for almost two years, and then I did some upgrades and now it is not fading anymore. Not sure if there is a configuration option for this.